# Android 14 Samsung Phones Activity Transition Animations Works Awkward

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-activity, android-14

When the android application is updated on Android 14 Samsung mobile phones, custom activity animations are broken and the problem continues until you restart the phone. I am also experiencing this error in the official Instagram android application.

At first I thought the problem was about `overridePendingTransition` and I changed it to `overrideActivityTransition` but the problem still persists. This problem does not always happen.
Animations sometimes work properly but sometimes Awkward.

Comment: Give me some more information about the issue

Comment: Seems related to https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/3644 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/300310597
Can you confirm if you're checking on beta version of Android 14 or stable version?